# VS Code: how to align function arguments in C++?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I wanna split function calls like `printf("%d %d %d\n", 1, 2, 3)` over multiple lines. In sublime text, when I put my cursor right before `1` and hit enter, the `1` immediately lines up right with the start of the format string:

```
printf("%d %d %d\n",
       1, 2, 3)
```

When I do the same in VS Code, the `1` only lines up with the start of the function call (i.e. the current indentation level). If I want to get the `1` to line up with the format string I have to tab it over and then hit the spacebar to insert the appropriate amount of spaces...

If instead of moving over the argument I highlight the two lines and do `Format selection` it lines up perfectly.

Is there any way to get that to happen automatically (via some settings or by some extension) like how it does with sublime text? It'd be a real time saver!